# ¿Me pueden ayudar con una interfaz en python? (transformar datos)

Tags: python

Tengo que usar python para el backend de una aplicación que se conecta a una aplicación muy vieja, y esta entrega la información a través de algo parecido a API, pero no son API, son más bien archivos propios de intercambio, en un formato algo parecido a esto (los datos son falsos)

```
cuenta,2873190022,sucursal,372,movimiento,00,cantidad,298,clave de seguimiento,1000
```

Ya tengo las rutinas que se conectan al servidor y me traen la información, y ya también tengo las rutinas que escriben de vuelta al servidor, ese no es problema. Mi problema en si, es la integración de la información. El problema es que cuando envío la información al servidor, tengo que volver a enviarle la información en este formato, con exactamente la misma cantidad y nombre de los campos, pero con los datos modificados, si es que se modificaron, por ejemplo, un resultado para esta transacción podría ser (nuevamente son datos falsos)

```
cuenta,2873190022,sucursal,372,movimiento,33,cantidad,100,clave de seguimiento,1040
```

Obviamente no puedo cambiar el código del sistema con el que me conecto, porque no tengo acceso a el, además de ser muy viejo y quien sabe en qué lenguaje esté

Lo que quiero es ver cómo le puedo hacer para separar lo que me llega en dos listas, una con las "llaves", digámoslo así, y otra con los valores, para que pueda operar sobre ellos, y después reintegrar las listas en un solo string para enviar. No se si me explico, se los agradecería mucho

Los parámetros no siempre son iguales, cuenta, sucursal y movimiento si, y siempre están en la misma posición, pero dependiendo del movimiento puede que traiga cantidad o cualquier otra cosa, por eso necesito procesar los parámetros en una lista

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, hay que hacer dos cosas:

I. Separar la respuesta que recibes del sistema en dos listas, llamémosle `keys` y `vals`. Eso está fácil:

```
s = "cuenta,2873190022,sucursal,372,movimiento,00,cantidad,298,clave de seguimiento,1000"
```

Primero separar en tokens, por comas:

```
tokens = s.split(',')
```

Eso te da una lista de cada elemento del string, separado por comas, ahora tienes que separar esa lista de `tokens` en `keys` y `vals`:

```
keys = tokens[::2]
vals = tokens[1::2]
```

Y ya, puedes trabajar con ellos como gustes. En esta caso, por ejemplo, suponemos que hay un proceso que al final hace que:

```
vals[3] = 100
vals[4] = 1040
```

---

II. Ahora tienes que crear un string a partir de estas dos listas, pero combinándolas elemento por elemento, como si fueran un zipper:

```
r = [None]*(len(keys)+len(vals))
r = ','.join(result)
```

Y ya, la cadena `r` tiene el valor `'cuenta,2873190022,sucursal,372,movimiento,00,cantidad,100,clave de seguimiento,1040'`